# How can I call the XmlDocument.Load method asynchronously?

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, rss, xmldocument

I have working code to read an RSS feed that uses:

```
Dim doc As New XmlDocument
doc.Load("http://...")
Dim channel As XmlElement = doc("rss")("channel")
Dim items As XmlNodeList = channel.GetElementsByTagName("item")
```

Unfortunately the doc.Load call causes the rest of the program to become unresponsive until it finishes.

What's the best way to perform the load asynchronously and have a callback function to process the data?

**Edit**: Here's the code I've tried using WebClient - the `Load` method is still lagging:

```
Private Sub checkResults()
    'request rss feed
    Dim w As New System.Net.WebClient
    AddHandler w.OpenReadCompleted, AddressOf rssReadCallback
    w.OpenReadAsync(New Uri("http://..."))
End Sub

Private Sub rssReadCallback(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Net.OpenReadCompletedEventArgs)
    Dim reply As Stream = Nothing

    Try
        reply = CType(e.Result, Stream)

        Dim doc As New XmlDocument
        doc.Load(reply) ' This line takes forever to complete
        Dim channel As XmlElement = doc("rss")("channel")
        Dim items As XmlNodeList = channel.GetElementsByTagName("item")

        '...


    Finally
        If Not reply Is Nothing Then
            reply.Close()
        End If
    End Try
```

The rssReadCallback method is executed fairly quickly after calling checkResults, but then the UI freezes during the `Load` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe `XmlDocument` itself has any asynchronous functionality built into it, but you could easily use the thread pool (or the Task Parallel Library if you're using .NET 4) to load the document in a background thread just like any other long-running operation. You can then marshal a call back to the UI thread to handle the document when it's loaded.

(If you *are* using .NET 4, I'd strongly recommend that you use `XDocument` instead of `XmlDocument`; LINQ to XML is a lovely API.)

Another option would be to use [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) to download the document first, and then load it when it's already in memory - `WebClient` already supports asynchronous operations, so you can simply add appropriate event handlers and they'll be executed in your UI thread automatically.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I tried using WebClient but it turns out the XMLDocument `Load` method is very slow reading the stream even if it's already downloaded. I think I'll have to make a new thread. Can I use the `BackgroundWorker` class or is it deprecated?

Comment: @Andrew: How *exactly* did you try with `WebClient`? Did you still just give it the same URL? You can definitely use BackgroundWorker though - it's not deprecated at all.

Comment: I've added the WebClient Async code I used to the question. I think the `Load` call I've indicated must be taking a long time to parse the document - I assumed it was the download.

Comment: @Andrew: `OpenReadCompleted` isn't raised when *all* of the data is fetched, just when it's *starting* to read. You should be using the `DownloadDataCompleted` event and the `DownloadData` method.

Comment: Fantastic, that solved the problem. I should've read the documentation more closely. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can load it in another thread. Microsoft has a KB explaining how to use threads with Visual Basic .NET:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315577